# Comparison of factor structures using AIC and BIC

Tags: aic, confirmatory-factor, bic

I tested using a CFA two versions of the same questionnaire: the long version (i.e., 30 items) and the shortened version (i.e., 20 items). It is possible to compare these factor structures using AIC and BIC indices? The sample size is the same as well as the estimation method (CFA implemented using ML).

Thank you.

Comment: Does the discussion here (http://www.talkstats.com/threads/sem-comparing-models-with-different-variables.38047/) help? I have some initial thoughts, though I would be more interested in what others have to say.